# Should I grade my property or put dirt against chain link fence?

Tags: fence, grading

I recently installed a chain link fence. It's a long story why, but our neighbor's property is about 6" lower in elevation in some spots where the chain link fence is. We installed the chain link fence on the lower elevation because the existing wood fence we were installing was at that elevation. Now we want to know if we should just fill in the gap between the fence and our property (high side), or should we grade our side of the property so that it meets the bottom of the chain link fence? We would rather just fill in the gaps, but I want to know if this could cause any problems.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you do grade it make sure water does not flow towards the house.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this is far from the house, and the house is already at a higher elevation than the fence and surrounding soil.

Comment: What is the fence intended to keep in or out?

Comment: Just my dog. I'm not worried about him digging under the fence or jumping it. He didn't do that with the old one.

Comment: Voting to close. This is mostly a matter of prerogative.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1):

I would shave down the high side (left side in picture) from a distance of 2 or ft and use that to fill under the fence. Assuming the fence is on the property line this would transfer some soil to your neighbor's property. You could assume he won't mind, but it would be best to discuss it with him first.

If this fence is designed to contain a dog who is or might be a digger, you might have to place cobbles or concrete "stone" blocks with decorative side toward the neighbor, under the fence and fill on the back side. Of course, it might look strange to have blocks only under some sections of the chain link fence.

Comment: Thank you for your response! There isn't space under the fence. It basically touches the ground.